# Trigger not updating dependency property after value has been set in code

Tags: wpf, triggers

I have two control template triggers (IsMouseOver and IsPressed). They set the Foo property correctly after the application starts. However, after i I have set Foo in code, the triggers cease to function (the set Foo is never called).

Why?

Comment: How about showing us some XAML and/or code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Triggers` have a lower [precedence](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms743230%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) than explicitly set values, if you want to set a value which should be changeable by a `Trigger` you can use a `Setter` for example.

[`SetCurrentValue`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.dependencyobject.setcurrentvalue.aspx) might also work out depending on your needs.

Comment: Precedence works at different levels as well. If you set the property on the control but the trigger is in a style it will also be ignored. Rule of thumb is to set the property in the same place as the trigger.

Comment: @JRoughan: I am well aware of this, in the precedence listing "properties on the control" are called `local value`, that is what "explicitly set values" come down to as well.

Comment: Easy now; I assumed you were aware of this. Yours was a good answer and got my vote. I added the comment to prevent another common stumbling block for future readers of this question.